# How to set the width of a Java ComboBox as wide as the JPanel it's in?

Tags: java, swing, layout, width, jcombobox

I was wondering if there's a way to set a ComboBox' width as wide as the JPanel it's in.
I have the following code-snippet:

```
    public newPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));

        String[] example = new String[] {"one, "two", "three", "four"};

        JComboBox cBox = new JComboBox(levels);
        cBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));

        this.add(new JLabel("This is text that goes above the ComboBox:"));
        this.add(cBox);
    }
```

You can see that I said that I wanted the ComboBox to be 300px wide, but is there a way to automatically set it as wide as the Panel it's in?
Something like `cBox.setPreferredWidth(max);`  (I know that doesn't exist, it's just to display my way of thinking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **is there a way to automatically set it as wide as the Panel it's in?**

You probably want to let the layout manager take care of this.

If you *don't* set the preferred width, `GridLayout` will make sure the combo box fills the entire panel horizontally.

This snippet...

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));

        String[] example = new String[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

        JComboBox cBox = new JComboBox(example);
        //cBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));

        panel.add(new JLabel("This is text that goes above the ComboBox:"));
        panel.add(cBox);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel border"));

        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

...results in

[image]

If this isn't flexible enough for you, I would recommend you to use a `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

As some others already pointed out, making the comboBox fill the space is supported by several LayoutManagers. The *exact* behaviour is at the discretion of the concrete manager. No way around learning what they are doing :-) Then decide which behaviour you want and choose an appropriate one, not forgetting that there are excellent 3rd party LayoutManagers around.

Guessing a bit: you want the comboBox extend to the complete width, but keep its height a "reasonable" one-liner when increasing the frame height. BoxLayout can do that, with a little help from your code: it does respect a component's maximum hint, provided there is one. Some components (like JLabel) return something reasonable, others (like JComboBox) don't.

Below is a snippet which adds a max size to the comboBox.

```
    JComponent panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    String[] levels = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

    JComboBox cBox = new JComboBox(levels) {

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            Dimension dim = super.getMaximumSize();
            dim.height = getPreferredSize().height;
            return dim;
        }

    };

    panel.add(new JLabel("This is text that goes above the ComboBox:"));
    panel.add(cBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GridBagLayout` as the layout manager with filling constraints HORIZONTAL:

```
this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
this.add(cBox,new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a BoxLayout and displaying elements top to bottom.
It will automatically use their maximum size

You can look at that if you want to understand more deeply :
http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/getting_to_know_boxlayout

```
    class newPanel extends JPanel{
        public newPanel(){
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            String[] levels = new String[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

            JComboBox cBox = new JComboBox(levels);
            //cBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));

            add(new JLabel("This is text that goes above the ComboBox:"));
            add(cBox);
        }
   }
```